# Jira: Adding a Link to in issue doesn't work for a project

Tags: jira

I've been using Jira recently and I came across a problem that I don't know how to fix it.

I have to Jira instances. when I try to link an issue to one on the other instance it doesn't link. It used to work but now it won't.

every time I try to link it I will get this even though for other projects it wasn't needed :
[image]

and when press authenticate  I get this page:
afterward, when I press the link nothing changes.

Please if you are familiar with this problem help me.
[image]
afterward, when I press the link nothing changes.

I tried to link the other way and it's working but I still can't identify where the problem is.

Please if you are familiar with this problem help me.

Answer (score 0):

It's all about **Application Links**.

Some server changes (like reverse proxy, update in web.xml, etc.) or changes in the admin user account may break the links.

You need the check Application Links between two instances; if there is a problem, try to solve that first.

If not, remove the application link from both instances and add it again.

By the way, if the users in the two Jira instances are same, enable the "OAuth" in the application links (and also be sure that the admin account is same on these two instances.)

***Sources:***

1. [Linking issues](https://confluence.atlassian.com/jiracoreserver084/linking-issues-979408240.html)
2. [Application Links](https://support.atlassian.com/jira-cloud-administration/docs/use-applinks-to-link-to-atlassian-products/)

Comment: Hello And thank you for your answer. I don't think it's related to my Application Links since I can link to remote issues on other projects that's why i don't think it's OAuth problem either.

Comment: So, it's only happening at a specific project, right?

Comment: yes and when i checked the permission of the other project it's similar to the project that doesn't link.